# Angularjs Bad Request (400)

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am trying to consume a REST service that I created in a Spring API, when I test it with Swagger it behaves as expected, but when trying to use it from my UI I get a:

```
 rest/login/getCredentials 400 (Bad Request)
```

I normally use `@RequestBody` but in this case I used `@RequestParam`, could that be the source of trouble? When I call the service from the UI the thread seems to stop at the controler and the only thing the console shows me is:

```
2016-03-10 19:15:02.997  INFO 8852 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-03-10 19:15:03.016  INFO 8852 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
```

**JS**

```
  $scope.recoverPassword = function(){


    $http.post('rest/login/getCredentials',$scope.email).success(function (loginResponse) {

      if(loginResponse.code == 200){
        alert(loginResponse.codeMessage);

      }else{
        alert(loginResponse.codeMessage);
      }

      $scope.showLogin = true;

    });

  };
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCredentials", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional
public LoginResponse getCredentials(@RequestParam("email")String email){

    LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse();
    Boolean state = loginService.getCredentials(email);

    if(state){
        response.setCode(200);
        response.setCodeMessage("Credentials send, please check your email.");
    }else{
        response.setCode(401);
        response.setCodeMessage("Invalid email.");
    }

    return response;

}
```

The browser's debugger only shows the Request Payload as: 'somemail@mail.com'

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction, I'm pretty sure it must be a very dumb mistaken.

EDIT: Changed from @Param to Body for the lols and it worked, still I would like to know why it doesn't work with Param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$http.post('rest/login/getCredentials',$scope.email)`, as per the api `post(url, data, [config]);`, you are sending emailId as request content and not as request param. So you controller doesnt get the email address when you use @param.

You can also check the network tab in browser, email address is going as post body content not as url request param